# ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received. Predicting new test data with tfidf and selection feature

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So i have build a model with sklearn Naive Bayes classifier.
I need to know how to predict a sentence with input

when i just hardcode the sentence its work fine, look like this

```
new_sentence = ['its so broken']
new_testdata_tfidf= tfidf.transform(new_sentence) 
#transform it to matrix to see the score TFIDF on the training data
fit_feature_selection = selection.transform(new_testdata_tfidf) 
#transform the new data to see if the feature remove or not, because after tfidf i use chi2 selection feature.
predicted = classifier.predict(feature_selection )
#then predict it. the classificaiton out, the class is -1 which is the correct answer
```

i need to type the text data with hand as **an input** so I use like this

```
new_sentence = input[('')] 
#i input the same sentence its so broken 
new_testdata_tfidf= tfidf.transform(new_sentence) 
#transform it to matrix to see the score TFIDF on the training data
fit_feature_selection = selection.transform(new_testdata_tfidf) 
#transform the new data to see if the feature remove or not, because after tfidf i use chi2 selection feature.
predicted = classifier.predict(feature_selection )
```

but it give me output

```
  File "C:\Users\Myfile\OneDrive\Desktop\model.py", line 170, in <module>
   new_testdata_tfidf= tfidf.transform(new_sentence) 

  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1898, in transform
    X = super().transform(raw_documents)

  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1265, in transform
    "Iterable over raw text documents expected, "

ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.
```

How to resolve this?
any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried passing the new sentence as an array? i.e.

```
new_testdata_tfidf= tfidf.transform([new_sentence])
```

The first instance you are passing an array with one string element and the other you are simply passing a string

Comment: Thank you its just work. sorry cant upvote I'm new(less than 15 rep on me). appreciate a lot!

Comment: thanks again, this worked for me, placing the string variable into brackets [ ]

bag_of_words_for_message = bag_of_words_trans.transform([message])

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass the list of strings with `new_sentence = input[('')]`  in your code, then you might want to replace it with

```
new_sentence = [input()]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sdtv Thanks for your confirmation. No issues, I am new here too. All the best.